I would like to know the data packets on mightysat
If your English skills are not good, speaking may be awkward.
I completed the part of receiving data by connecting mightysat with Bluetooth using python.
However, I am struggling to figure out how to parse the received data.
I would really appreciate your help.

what data are you trying to parse? ... what is the problem thst you are having?

I need breaths rate and pulse rate.

The data comes in hexadecimal, but I don't know which of those data is the one I want.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please update your question with what the UUIDs are for the BLE services and characteristics. Also, give examples of the hex days you are recieving.
